# Share Pyramid configuration with a CLI script

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a standalone python CLI script (which usually i run with crontab) which I want to integrate into my `Pyramid` app in terms of accessing `Pyramid` app configuration and load environment.

When i used Django that could be done like this:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from myapp import settings

setup_environ(settings)
```

What is the best practice to do the same stuff with Pyramid? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyramid provides the `bootstrap` api to do this. Docs attached below.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/commandline.html#writing-a-script

```
from pyramid.paster import bootstrap
env = bootstrap('/path/to/my/development.ini#another')
```

Comment: Hm ... my comment disappeared. This is not exactly what I think about. It requires to know `config_uri`, but I thought to keep that logic in `Pyramid` app (so, only one place in the code manage loading of config files and knows *.ini paths) and just import somehow filled settings object.

Comment: Your Pyramid app has no idea where the INI file is either. There's no janky global settings module in Pyramid applications so you have to specify a path.

Comment: Ok, thank you. At the end the *.ini it's not a big deal to specify.